# Excel changing file path

Tags: excel, vba

I did a macro for Excel, but the final part isn't working as expected. It should save the xls file as xlsx in the same folder, but Excel tries to save it to C:[...]AppData/Roaming/. The objective path is in another PC over a Lan network, I have the feeling that that is the problem.

I'll only post the last part, as that is the one with the problem. In the original code, the Dim statement is at the start of the whole thing.

First I tried this

```
Dim FirstSheetName As String
    FirstSheetName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FirstSheetName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Then I tried this one just to be sure

```
Dim FirstSheetName As String
FirstSheetName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "\\100.0.0.0\2023\" & FirstSheetName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

I dont need the file to be macro enabled as there are no macros in that book, I did it just to check if that was the problem.

Edit: I tried using two file paths to check, here are the results:

ThisWorkbook.Path: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART ActiveWorkbook.FullName: \100.0.0.0[...]\2023\June.XLS

PD: I have no formal education in programing/coding, so my code might be inefficient and/or kinda ugly. Also, I changed the path numbers (1XX.X.X.X) from the original code to 0, I have no idea if it's safe to post those online and better safe than sorry.

Comment: Can you [map the network path to a drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-29ce55d1-34e3-a7e2-4801-131475f9557d)

Comment: What does `ThisWorkbook.Path` return?

Comment: Is 2023 really a share name? Or should it be \\server\share\2023

Comment: 1. I cant map the path drive using those instructions, "Map network drive" is replaced by "Add network drive" (but Im 100% conected to at least one network drive)
2. I tried using two file paths to check, here are the results:
ThisWorkbook.Path: C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART
ActiveWorkbook.FullName: \\100.0.0.0\[...]\2023\June.XLS
3. When I click on the bar to check the path it shows the ActiveWorkbook.FullName folder

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is *the workbook where the code is running* - looks like that's maybe your "personal.xlsb" workbook (personal macro workbook).  `ActiveWorkbook` is the workbook which is currently active on the screen.  They're not always the same workbook, so is that the source of your problem?